# ioutils.WriteFile() not respecting permissions

Tags: go, file-permissions

I'm trying to use ioutils.WriteFile() but for some reason it's ignoring the 0777 permissions I'm giving it.

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    // normal permissions
    if err := ioutil.WriteFile("cant-touch-this-0644", []byte{}, 0644); err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }


    // full permissions
    if err := ioutil.WriteFile("cant-touch-this-0777", []byte{}, 0777); err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }


    // normal permissions + chmod to full
    if err := ioutil.WriteFile("cant-touch-this-mixed", []byte{}, 0755); err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }

    if err := os.Chmod("cant-touch-this-mixed", 0777); err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }
}
```

The output I get from this is:

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r--  1 edson edson    0 May  9 17:19  cant-touch-this-0644
-rwxr-xr-x  1 edson edson    0 May  9 17:19  cant-touch-this-0777
-rwxrwxrwx  1 edson edson    0 May  9 17:19  cant-touch-this-mixed
```

Which means:

- The first scenario (0644) worked
- The second (0777) was ignored
- The only way I can get full 0777 permissions is by using a `os.Chmod` (like in the third scenario)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is unrelated to Go or `ioutil.WriteFile` specifically: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask

Comment: @JimB If you write that as an answer I'll mark it as the chosen answer.

Answer (score 3):

As the comment on this question says, this is because [umask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) worked. unmask controls how file permissions are set for newly created files. When umask is 022, a file you want to create as 666 will be 644 (removes a write permission from group and other permissions). You can check your directory's umask with `umask` command.